# Performance test on matrix computation

Tags: c, algorithm, performance

I am trying to compute all the 3x3 matrices that have an inverse in Z(N) where N is 5 and 13. Basicle I compute the determinant of the matrix modulo N, and if the result is relatively prime with N then it has an invers. I need to do this for N equal 26 and 256 also, but it will take to long to find them.

So when I so that it takes too much for generating all the matrices for N 26, I decided to cut the number of matrices tested, by eliminating all the matrices that will have determinant 0. So I started implementing the pruning section of the algorithm. The funny thing was that with it, it took longer to find the result.

To find the answer to the performance decrease I tried visual studio CPU profiling and AMD uProf, to find the hot regions. It did not help.

As a final Hail Mary I tried commenting out the optimizations inside the switch one by one, starting from the case 8. The following are the results of those tests, and as you can see, while the number of tests increases (the number of compleate matrices and the number of determinants computed) the time it takes is lower.

```
D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1832992
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10562854484
time: 83s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1865344
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10575805824
time: 81s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1865344
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10575805824
time: 81s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1893280
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10585310112
time: 80s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1907600
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10590078096
time: 80s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1922000
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10594847952
time: 78s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1937500
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10599672564
time: 78s

D:\hill_cipher\x64\Release>hill_cipher.exe
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1953125
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10604499373
time: 74s
```

For the life of me, I do not know why it takes longer with the optimizations. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a % b == 0) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}

// second order determinant
/* maxtrix column based
    0 2
    1 3
*/
int det2(int *mat) {
    return mat[0] * mat[3] - mat[1] * mat[2];
}

// third order determinant
/* maxtrix column based
    0 3 6
    1 4 7
    2 5 8
*/
int det3(int* mat) {
    return (mat[0] * mat[4] * mat[8]
          + mat[1] * mat[5] * mat[6]
          + mat[2] * mat[3] * mat[7]
          - mat[6] * mat[4] * mat[2]
          - mat[7] * mat[5] * mat[0]
          - mat[8] * mat[3] * mat[1]);
}

#define PRINT3MAT(matrix) printf("\t%d %d %d\tautokey\n\t%d %d %d\n\t%d %d %d\n\n", matrix[0], matrix[3], matrix[6], \
                                                                                    matrix[1], matrix[4], matrix[7], \
                                                                                    matrix[2], matrix[5], matrix[8]);

#define PRINT2MAT(matrix) printf("\t%d %d\tautokey\n\t%d %d\n\n", matrix[0], matrix[2], \
                                                                  matrix[1], matrix[3]);


bool autokey2(int* matrix) {
    /* maxtrix column based
        0 2
        1 3
    */
    bool result = true;

    do {
        if ((matrix[0] * matrix[0] + matrix[2] * matrix[1]) != 1) { // M(0,0)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[0] * matrix[2] + matrix[2] * matrix[3]) != 0) { // M(0,1)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1] * matrix[0] + matrix[3] * matrix[1]) != 0) { // M(1,0)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1] * matrix[2] + matrix[3] * matrix[3]) != 1) { // M(1,1)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (false);

    return result;
}

bool autokey3(int* matrix) {
    /* maxtrix column based
        0 3 6
        1 4 7
        2 5 8
    */
    bool result = true;

    do {
        if ((matrix[0] * matrix[0] + matrix[3] * matrix[1] + matrix[6] * matrix[2]) != 1) { // M(0,0)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[0] * matrix[3] + matrix[3] * matrix[4] + matrix[6] * matrix[5]) != 0) { // M(0,1)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[0] * matrix[6] + matrix[3] * matrix[7] + matrix[6] * matrix[8]) != 0) { // M(0,2)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1] * matrix[0] + matrix[4] * matrix[1] + matrix[7] * matrix[2]) != 0) { // M(1,0)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1] * matrix[3] + matrix[4] * matrix[4] + matrix[7] * matrix[5]) != 1) { // M(1,1)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1] * matrix[6] + matrix[4] * matrix[7] + matrix[7] * matrix[8]) != 0) { // M(1,2)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[2] * matrix[0] + matrix[5] * matrix[1] + matrix[8] * matrix[2]) != 0) { // M(2,0)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[2] * matrix[3] + matrix[5] * matrix[4] + matrix[8] * matrix[5]) != 0) { // M(2,1)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[2] * matrix[6] + matrix[5] * matrix[7] + matrix[8] * matrix[8]) != 1) { // M(2,2)
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (false);

    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    bool key_test[4][256];
    int N[] = { 5, 13, 26, 256 };
    long long int possible_keys = 0;
    long long int autokey = 0;
    int matrix[9];
    bool valid[9];
    int pos;
    int val;
    int cst;
    int max_pos, max_pn;
    time_t start_t, end_t;
    long long int nr_teste;

    // generate all inversable values
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N[i]; j++) {
            if (gcd(j, N[i]) == 1) {
                key_test[i][j] = true;
            } else {
                key_test[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    start_t = time(NULL);
    for (int d = 3; d <= 3; d++) {
        max_pos = d * d - 1;

        if (d == 2) {
            max_pn = 4;
        } else {
            max_pn = 2;
        }

        // check all the Z(n) rings
        for (int pn = 0; pn < max_pn; pn++) {
            //init matrix
            for (int i = 0; i < d*d; i++) {
                matrix[i] = 0;
                valid[i] = false;
            }
            possible_keys = 0;
            autokey = 0;
            nr_teste = 0;

            // generate matrix
            pos = 0;
            while (pos >= 0) {

                if (valid[pos] == false) {
                    matrix[pos] = 0;
                    valid[pos] = true;
                } else {
                    if (matrix[pos] + 1 < N[pn]) {
                        matrix[pos] ++;
                    } else {
                        // No more values for this position
                        valid[pos] = false;
                        //matrix[pos] = 0;
                        pos--;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                // For some reason if I add this, it will be slower
                if (d == 3) {
                    // pruning
                    switch (pos)
                    {
                    case 2: {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 3 6
                            1 4 7
                            2 5 8
                        */
                        if (matrix[2] == 0 && matrix[1] == 0 && matrix[0] == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 5: {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 3 6
                            1 4 7
                            2 5 8
                        */
                        if (matrix[5] == 0 && matrix[4] == 0 && matrix[3] == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (matrix[5] <= matrix[2] && matrix[5] != 0) {
                            cst = matrix[2] / matrix[5];
                            if ((matrix[2] % matrix[5] == 0) && (cst * matrix[4] == matrix[1]) && (cst * matrix[3] == matrix[0])) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (matrix[2] != 0) {
                                cst = matrix[5] / matrix[2];
                                if ((matrix[5] % matrix[2] == 0) && (cst * matrix[1] == matrix[4]) && (cst * matrix[0] == matrix[3])) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 6: {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 3 6
                            1 4 7
                            2 5 8
                        */
                        if (matrix[6] == 0 && matrix[3] == 0 && matrix[0] == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 7: {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 3 6
                            1 4 7
                            2 5 8
                        */
                        if (matrix[7] == 0 && matrix[4] == 0 && matrix[1] == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (matrix[7] <= matrix[6] && matrix[7] != 0) {
                            cst = matrix[6] / matrix[7];
                            if ((matrix[6] % matrix[7] == 0) && (cst * matrix[4] == matrix[3]) && (cst * matrix[1] == matrix[0])) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (matrix[6] != 0) {
                                cst = matrix[7] / matrix[6];
                                if ((matrix[7] % matrix[6] == 0) && (cst * matrix[3] == matrix[4]) && (cst * matrix[0] == matrix[1])) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 8: {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 3 6
                            1 4 7
                            2 5 8
                        */
                        if (matrix[8] == 0 && matrix[7] == 0 && matrix[6] == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (matrix[8] == 0 && matrix[5] == 0 && matrix[2] == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // does not cat much and is rare
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                } 
                //else {
                //  switch (pos)
                //  {
                //  case 1: {
                //      /* maxtrix column based
                //          0 2
                //          1 3
                //      */
                //      if (matrix[1] == 0 && matrix[0] == 0) {
                //          continue;
                //      }
                //      break;
                //  }
                //  case 2: {
                //      /* maxtrix column based
                //          0 2
                //          1 3
                //      */
                //      if (matrix[0] == 0 && matrix[2] == 0) {
                //          continue;
                //      }
                //      break;
                //  }
                //  case 3: {
                //      /* maxtrix column based
                //          0 2
                //          1 3
                //      */
                //      if (matrix[1] == 0 && matrix[3] == 0) {
                //          continue;
                //      }
                //      if (matrix[2] == 0 && matrix[3] == 0) {
                //          continue;
                //      }
                //      // does not cat much and is rare
                //      break;
                //  }
                //  }
                //}


                if (pos != max_pos) {
                    if (valid[pos] == true) {
                        pos++;
                    }
                } else {
                    // we have a complete matrix
                    nr_teste++;

                    if (d == 3) {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 3 6
                            1 4 7
                            2 5 8
                        */
                        val = matrix[0] * matrix[4] * matrix[8]
                            + matrix[1] * matrix[5] * matrix[6]
                            + matrix[2] * matrix[3] * matrix[7]
                            - matrix[6] * matrix[4] * matrix[2]
                            - matrix[7] * matrix[5] * matrix[0]
                            - matrix[8] * matrix[3] * matrix[1];
                    } else {
                        /* maxtrix column based
                            0 2
                            1 3
                        */
                        val = matrix[0] * matrix[3] - matrix[1] * matrix[2];
                    }

                    val = val % N[pn];

                    if (val < 0) {
                        val += N[pn]; // make sure the result is positive
                    }

                    if (key_test[pn][val]) { // val == 0 will return false 
                        possible_keys++;
                        
                        if (d == 3) {
                            if (autokey3(matrix)) {
                                autokey++;
                                //PRINT3MAT(matrix);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (autokey2(matrix)) {
                                autokey++;
                                //PRINT2MAT(matrix);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }

            printf("d: %d    N: %3d    possible keys: %10lld    autokey: %lld    nr teste: %11lld\n", d, N[pn], possible_keys, autokey, nr_teste);

            //break;
        }
        //break;
    }

    end_t = time(NULL);
    printf("time: %llds\n", end_t - start_t);

    return 0;
}
```

**Update 1**
I switched to linux and used perf analyze the performance counters. For the "optimized" version I obtained:

```
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1832992
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10562854484
time: 91s

 Performance counter stats for './hill_cipher':

         91.141,55 msec task-clock                #    0,999 CPUs utilized          
   368.707.285.660      cycles                    #    4,045 GHz                      (83,33%)
             3.535      context-switches          #    0,039 K/sec                  
                52      page-faults               #    0,001 K/sec                  
        29.044.482      cache-misses                                                  (83,33%)
   368.706.753.424      cycles                    #    4,045 GHz                      (66,66%)
   861.658.443.048      instructions              #    2,34  insn per cycle           (83,33%)
    94.135.383.666      branches                  # 1032,848 M/sec                    (83,33%)
     1.571.177.575      branch-misses             #    1,67% of all branches          (83,34%)

      91,219342601 seconds time elapsed

      91,079478000 seconds user
       0,063996000 seconds sys
```

And without the pruning I obtained:

```
d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1953125
d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10604499373
time: 78s

 Performance counter stats for './hill_cipher':

         78.072,56 msec task-clock                #    1,000 CPUs utilized          
   315.655.551.124      cycles                    #    4,043 GHz                      (83,33%)
               274      context-switches          #    0,004 K/sec                  
                52      page-faults               #    0,001 K/sec                  
        21.543.133      cache-misses                                                  (83,33%)
   315.623.715.271      cycles                    #    4,043 GHz                      (66,67%)
   761.423.725.679      instructions              #    2,41  insn per cycle           (83,33%)
    57.487.582.295      branches                  #  736,335 M/sec                    (83,33%)
       418.093.257      branch-misses             #    0,73% of all branches          (83,33%)

      78,077203434 seconds time elapsed

      78,066022000 seconds user
       0,007999000 seconds sys
```

The compiler commands were:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -m64 -O3 -flto -fPIC -Iinclude -c -o bin/release_64/obj/hill_cipher.o src/hill_cipher.cpp
gcc -g -m64 -O3 -flto -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Iinclude -o bin/release_64/hill_cipher  bin/release_64/obj/hill_cipher.o
```

Comment: Have you tried running these various versions with a profiler? I would *speculate* that the "clever" versions suffer due to branching cost. I can reproduce your general observation: `d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1832992 ; d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10562854484 ; time: 132s ;; d: 3    N:   5    possible keys:    1488000    autokey: 4    nr teste:     1953125 ; d: 3    N:  13    possible keys: 9726417792    autokey: 4    nr teste: 10604499373 ; time: 109s`

Comment: I did not measure the number of failed branches.

Comment: What are your compiler flags? Can you measure how many operations each pruning test saves? You could probably also speed things up by using bitwise operations to simplify tests  - although this may require a different matrix representation.

Comment: I did not change the compiler flags. They are the standard ones for release from visual studio. I checked and the \O2 flag is set, with the Favor speed. But on all the tests, the flags were the same.

Comment: @njuffa I did some mesurements on another system, and posted an update. Can the difference in performance be only from the `branch-misses`? 
@tucuxi posted the flags too.

Comment: @Tandura It is probably not just branch mispredicts. Note that the total number of instructions executed is also significantly higher in the slow case, which probably is the cause of majority of time increase. That is probably due to (1) execution of additional compare instructions and branch instructions (2) branching interfering with certain compiler optimizations, from CSE (common subexpression elimination) to instruction scheduling (e.g. scheduling loads early). Look at generated machine code: increase in static instruction count may already hint at increase in dynamic instruction count.

Comment: I would recommend GPU programming as a more likely source of speedups.  See https://nextjournal.com/sdanisch/julia-gpu-programming for more on that.